# Download depot files into local disk without a client workspace

Tags: .net, perforce, p4api.net

I read one other post here that I can download a file from the Perforce depot into a local disk without a client workspace.  To extend that further, I need to download all files (text & binary) from a depot dir into my local disk.  Is this the correct p4 command to do that?

p4 print //depot/dir1/...

I have a few questions:

1. Will it download all sub directories as well as files from //depot/dir1/... or files only?
2. Will it keep the original names of the files that will be downloaded?
3. Where are the files located on the local disk given no local path is specified?

I'm using the p4api.net library.  Will this code do it?

```
    public void GetFiles(string DepotFilePath) 
    {
        P4Command cmd = new P4Command( _repository, "print", true, 
        String.Format( "{0}/...", DepotFilePath ));

        results = cmd.Run();
        if (results.Success)
        {
            //do something here
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure where in the local disk it will dump the files into?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to use a workspace?  You could even create one, use it, then delete it.  That might be easier than trying to use p4 print to get _all_ the files you need, and then parse that output stream into separate files.

Comment: You should define a workspace. The fact that you're asking questions such as "where in the local disk will it dump the files" means that you will benefit from defining a workspace, since that's how you tell Perforce those things.

Comment: The files from //Depot will be downloaded into any of a variety of PCs in a lab environment so I just want a simple way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5):

Simple solution requiring no platform-specific scripting tools:

```
p4 client -df TEMP_CLIENT
p4 -c TEMP_CLIENT --field View="//depot/dir1/... //TEMP_CLIENT/..." client -o | p4 client -i
p4 -c TEMP_CLIENT sync -p
p4 client -d TEMP_CLIENT
```

This will download all files/directories from `//depot/dir1` into your current directory.  If you want to specify a different directory, add `--field "Root=C:\Some Path"` to the first command in the same spot where the `View` is specified.

Answer (score 3):

`p4 print` will output the content onto the standard output (see the excellent [manual](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/print.html)). Therefore, to answer your questions in order:

1. It will "download" all files in all subdirectories, but it will only print the file content on stdout. It will not generate files on disk.
2. Yes, sort of, but not in the way you imagine. Within your stream on stdout, there will be lines like this: `//depot/path/to/file#5 - edit change 430530 (text)`, followed by the content of that particular file.
3. Nowhere, no files will be created on disk.

If you really don't want to create a client workspace for your task (why?), then you'd have to do something like the following:

1. Get a list of files with e.g. `p4 files` ([manual](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/files.html#1040665))
2. Iterate over this list and call `p4 print` for each file
3. Redirect the output of `p4 print` to a file on the local disk, adhering to the directory structure in the depot.

Comment: Is there another command to "get" files from P4 into a local drive without a workspace?  will the following print command work to download ALL files in a depot dir that preserves the original file names, "p4 print -q -o c:/local_dir //depot/path/... ?  Thanks.

Comment: I ran "p4 print -q -o C:\local_dir //depot/path/..." to download all files from depot using the Windows DOS shell but got "open for write: C:\local_dir: Access is denied."  What would be the correct p4 print syntax to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: You probably want `p4 print -q -o C:\local_dir\a_file //depot/path/...`

Answer (score 1):

#### One-Liner

For reference, here's a bash one liner that will do the manual procedure jhwist's answer:

```
for _file in $(p4 files //depot/dir/... | awk '{print $1}' | perl -ne '/(.*)#\d+$/ && print "$1\n"'); do p4 print -q $_file > /path/to/target/dir/$(basename $_file); done
```

The only bits you have to replace with the directories in question are `//depot/dir` and `/path/to/target/dir`. Note: the target directory has to already exist.

#### Explanation:

Pulling out what the `for` loop is iterating over:

```
$(p4 files //depot/dir/... | awk '{print $1}' | perl -ne '/(.*)#\d+$/ && print "$1\n"')
```

1. Get list of files from perforce directory in question
2. First column of the output is depot location of file, so extract it with `awk`
3. Depot location has `#revisionNumber` tacked on the end of it, so strip it off with `perl`

Answer (score 0):

So I've spent some time to get this to work under different scenarios in bash, and even though it is not dotnet specific I thought I'd share my results, as the concepts are universal.

You have two options to get files from remote:

1. Check out and sync a workspace mapping using a temporary client/workspace, like Sam Stafford wrote in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46800394/3968618). Here is that in bash with comments:

```
# p4 uses this global variable as client/workspace name by default.
# Alternatively, you can also use -c in every command.
P4CLIENT="TEMP_SCRIPT_CLIENT"

# mapping remote folder to relative workspace folder  (recursive)
wokspaceMapping="//depot/dir1/... //$P4CLIENT/..."
p4 client -d $P4CLIENT # make sure the workspace does not exist already
# Creating a client on the console gives an editor popup to confirm the
# workspace specification, unless you provide a specification on stdin.
# You can however generate one to stdout, and pipe the result to stdin again.
p4 --field View="$wokspaceMapping" --field Root="/some/local/path" client -o |
  p4 client -i
p4 sync -p # download all the files
p4 client -d $P4CLIENT # remove workspace when you are done.
```

2. Use `p4 print` to print the content of each file as [jhwist wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9079868/3968618) suggested, so you don't need to define a workspace at all. The disadvantage is that you have to handle each file individually, and create any directories yourself.

```
p4RemoteRoot="//depot/dir1"
# First, list files and strip output to file path
# because `p4 files` prints something like this:
# //depot/dir1/file1.txt#1 - add change 43444817 (text)
# //depot/dir1/folder/file2.txt#11 - edit change 43783713 (text)
files="$(p4 files $p4RemoteRoot/... | sed 's/\(.*\)#.*/\1/')"
for wsFile in $files; do
  # construct the local path from the remote one
  targetFile="$localPath/${wsFile#$p4RemoteRoot/}"
  # create the parent dir if it doesn't exist. p4 files doesn't list directories
  mkdir -p $(dirname $targetFile)
  # print the file content from remote and write that to the local file.
  p4 print -q $wsFile > $targetFile
done
```

Note: I couldn't find any documentation for the `--field` argument, but it seems you can use everything from "Form Fields" as specified in the docs: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v18.2/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_client.html

Answer (score 0):

Latest Perforce already supports it natively:

[image: o option for p4 print]

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_print.html#p4_print